# How can I tell how long Photos in Big Sur will be syncing?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, big-sur

I upgraded to Big Sur several weeks ago, and since realized that my Photos library was not set to sync with iCloud.

I've toggled it back on, but the library is a little over a month behind.

Unlike earlier versions of Photos there's no indication of where it is in the syncing process. Earlier versions had a progress bar in Preferences, and would show current progress at the bottom of the library.

My Library just says "Updating" - it's been 16+ hours now. I realize it's a pretty big library (~30K items), but some idea of how long it'll be would be nice.

Any way to see progress?

[image: Updating...]

Answer (score 1):

There is no progress bar since it isn't sure how long it will take. A progress bar will appear at times, depending on what it's doing, it hasn't been completely removed.

Unfortunately there is likely nothing you can do but wait.